# Como transformar uma lista em pandas dataframe?

Tags: lista, pandas, dataframe

Sou novo na linguagem, após a execução do seguinte código, o resultado do append feito é uma lista. Eu precisava dessas informações em dataframe, mas até agora não consegui encontrar uma maneira de converter sem perder informações. Sempre quando tento passar para dataframe (até com concat tentei), apenas uma das linhas aparece nele.

```
appended_data = []
for i in a:
 url = 'https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/{0}'.format(i)
 req = requests.get(url)
 code = req.status_code
 if code == 200:
     html = req.text
     receita = json.loads(html)
 dataframe=pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'Atividade Principal': [receita['atividade_principal'][0]['text']],
        'Situação cadastral': [receita['situacao']],
        'Status': [receita['status']],
        'Sócio 1 (role)': [receita['qsa'][0]['qual']],
        'Sócio 1': [receita['qsa'][0]['nome']],
        'Sócio 2 (role)': [receita['qsa'][1]['qual']],
        'Sócio 2': [receita['qsa'][1]['nome']],
        'Nome': [receita['nome']],
        'UF': [receita['uf']]

        }
    )
appended_data.append(dataframe)
appended_data
```

Como eu transformo a lista abaixo em dataframe? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

> não se esqueça de converter list para numpy arraye depois reshape

```
n = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lista).reshape(3,3), columns = list("ABC"))
print (n)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```